# What is antimatter and its role in the universe?

Tags: antimatter

As we know everything has its opposite. Like matter its opposite is antimatter. So why the universe is not made by antimatter instead of matter. And what is the main role of antimatter in the universe.

Comment: Asking what the main role of antimatter in the universe would be identical to asking what the role of matter is in the universe! Antimatter and matter are identical in their properties (that we know of), except that their charges are reversed. (you must remember there are charges other than electrical ones too!) It would make no difference if our universe was made of antimatter. The major question that arises is: Why is most of our universe made of matter, and where did the antimatter go?

Comment: Well this is technically not entierly true, only $CPT$ is conserved. The $CP$ symmetry is broken!

Answer (score 1):

Our everyday world, the world we live and die in is made out of matter, by definition. Our everyday world has been modeled successfully with the classical theories of Mechanics, Electrodynamics and Thermodynamics. The forces  of gravitation and electromagnetism  are the ones observable easily , again in the everyday environments. All these theories were finalized by the end of the 19th century when wise physicists thought that physics was completely described by the theories and only engineering was left .

Then discrepancies which the theories could not describe appeared.

a) [The photoelectric effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect)

b) [Black body radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation)

c) the [periodic table of elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table)

the new theory of [quantum mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics) appeared  to explain the phenomena.

At the same time experimental constructions, like [the vacuum tube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_tube), allowed the study, to start with, of electrons and allowed experiments that showed that [cosmic rays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_ray#Discovery) existed, particles with very large velocities.

Concurrently the special theory of relativity was developed as an extension of behavior of matter at high velocities .

The theory of Quantum Mechanics developed rapidly and by incorporating special relativity, i.e. a description of particles at high velocities, the first concept of the existence of antiparticles came  into light. [The positron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron#History), the anti particle of the electron.

Since then experiments in labs and using cosmic rays have disclosed a great plethora of particles and the theories predicted antiparticles for them , which have also been observed. The [antiproton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiproton) observation gave the Nobel to the discovers.

So all matter has its antimatter in theory. But a lot of energy , using the mass energy relations of special relativity, is needed from our matter universe to generate antimatter particles. The most commonly observed ones are the positrons because of their light mass, and the decays from radioactive nuclei. It is only at large accelerators and colliders that antiparticles of heavier particles can be observed, as well as with cosmic rays and their interactions.

Now why our observable universe is only matter and no antimatter stars, galaxies etc have been observed is another story, studied at the frontier of theoretical physics research.